# something wrong with OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

```
RoomNameSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelect(AdapterView<?>parent,View view,int position, long id){
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+"selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
});
```

I am green hand with android and when I use this code to get spinner information, the mistake is happen. The system said:

> AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener is wrong. Class must either be
>   declared abstract or implement abstract method
>   "OnNothingSelected(AdapterView)in OnItemSelectedListener.

How to solve that problem?

And one more question. I look a video of android to type those code. When the lecturer type down the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` the code:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelect()
```

is showing but my project cannot show the code. So I must type down the code. Is there something wrong with my android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Hello to answer your questions:

> Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method
>   "OnNothingSelected(AdapterView)in OnItemSelectedListener

you need to implement another function inside the listener called on notmingselected(), this is a void function so you can just leave it blank.

```
new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //yourcode
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            //leave blank or do something when nobody selects an item
        }
    }
```

> I look an video of android to type those code. When the lecturer type down the AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener the code @Override public void onItemSelect() is showing but my project cannot show the code. So I must type down the code. Is there something wrong with my android studio?

For your second question, Android studio does that sometimes, as you are typing the interface name it will show you options, if you press tab sometimes it will populate everything for you. If it doesn't just follow the errors that ask you to add the function I know it can be a pain.

A quick trick I use is sometimes looking the interface class on google and mainly the android developer page. In this case I just googled Adapter view and gave me the exact interface you are looking for and with the function it uses.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: No problem I updated my answer by adding the full interface implementation